# Converting an Image file into Binary in corona SDK

Tags: image, coronasdk, radix

Is there a way to convert an image file into binary or any other base in corona SDK so that I might be able to upload images as it causing problems when size increases or can any one suggest me the other way if it is not possible in corona?

Answer (score 0):

```
local path = system.pathForFile( "myfile.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )
local file = io.open( path, "r" )
local saveData = file:read( "*a" )
io.close( file )
```

For more info see: http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/02/14/reading-and-writing-files-in-corona/

Comment: If I am clearly understanding what you are trying to say then you are telling me to read just a text file but actually my problem is a little more difficult.Its about a JPEG image.